# How to get selected home page in wordpress using corcel?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, parsing

I'm using corcel for get worpdress info to laravel application.
[corcel](https://github.com/corcel/corcel)
I want to get selected home page with corcel from wordpress. I can not check it with slug (like /home) because it can be changed. 
In documentation nothing said about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the url of the current homepage using Option class:

```
$homepageUrl = Option::get('home');
```

and then just get the content through it:

```
file_get_contents($homepageUrl)
```